# Site speed image caching for image in pop-up

Tags: image, performance, image-processing, caching, magnific-popup

I'm creating a website that loads some images on first load, then if a user clicks on one of the images the same image opens in a popup but bigger (Lightbox).

My question is, is it better to just use the same large image and resize the dimensions for caching (So the user already has loaded the image) or is it better to first load a smaller thumbnail then the bigger image once the pop-up opens?

I'm trying to reduce site speed as much as possible as there are a lot of images.

I'm using Masonry for the site and Magnific Popup for the image expand if that helps.

the thumbnail image size is around 100kb whereas the larger image is between 200-300kb.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of any lightbox-type script is that they allow you to display preview images (thumbnails) on your page and load larger versions only when needed (e.g, when user clicks on the thumbnail). This greatly helps to reduce page weight and load time. Modern scripts (like fancybox) can display preview image while larger version is gradually appearing over it thus relieving users from staring at blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
image = "Your image link / location here"/ZoomService
```

image.Zoom(100)

--if you use MilkWar web coding use that

Comment: It's more of a lightbox as opposed to a Zoom in, it's just opening the same image but larger with more definition and higher res